# Firebase error: Can´t add ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my declaration code:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference("lifts");
```

Why can't I add the `ValueEventListener`? I tried the sample from the Firebase Guide. Here is the code:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

This works and I have no idea why?

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot item: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Or a logcat?

Comment: Error:(169, 37) error: incompatible types: <anonymous com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is, that you have to use a `com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener`. But I think you have an import for `com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener` in your imports on top of the file.

Because of this, the compiler tries to use `com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener` as default, which obviously fails.

To fix this, look through your imports and remove the entry for `com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener`. Then you can add `com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener`

This approach doesn't work if you have to use both of them. Then there's no other solution than using the full names (e.g. `com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener` instead of just `ValueEventListener`) for both or at least one.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the the imports and now it works! =)