# Error: Expected ')'

Tags: android

I'm getting an error that '`)`' is expected. I'm pretty sure this is because it's expecting a '`})`;' as I opened a parenthesis on this line '`databaseClients.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {`' . However, when I add/modify it in, the program still complains. Not sure why.

This is most probably a very stupid mistake!
Any help is appreciated. Cheers guys!

```
public class ViewProfile extends AppCompatActivity{

    ListView listviewClients;
    List<Clients> clientsList;

    DatabaseReference databaseClients;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);

        listviewClients = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewClients);
        databaseClients = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("clients");

        clientsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseClients.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                clientsList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot clientsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Clients clients = clientsSnapshot.getValue(Clients.class);

                    clientsList.add(clients);
                }
                ClientsList adapter = new ClientsList(ViewProfile.this, clientsList);
                listviewClients.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
When I add the }); this happens:
[image]

The error i get now is: Error:(42, 48) error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener .

Comment: you opened a `(` here `databaseClients.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {` but haven't closed it. add `);` after where you close the braces.

Comment: @RajeevSingh Cheers. But when I add the closing }); it seems to completely mess up the code (see the edit in my question). Do you know why?

Comment: that's another issue with your code, post the error you are getting after adding the braces.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458524/android-firebase-can%C2%B4t-add-valueeventlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably an issue with your imports.

You have to use a `com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener`. But I think you have an import for `com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener` in your imports on top of the file.

[Android Firebase: Can´t add ValueEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458524/android-firebase-can%C2%B4t-add-valueeventlistener)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ViewProfile extends AppCompatActivity{

ListView listviewClients;
List<Clients> clientsList;

DatabaseReference databaseClients;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);

    listviewClients = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewClients);
    databaseClients = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("clients");

    clientsList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseClients.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            clientsList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot clientsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Clients clients = clientsSnapshot.getValue(Clients.class);

                clientsList.add(clients);
            }
            ClientsList adapter = new ClientsList(ViewProfile.this, clientsList);
            listviewClients.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }

    });  //here is your problem
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, that is what I've been trying. But it seems to do something to the code, see the edit to my question. Thanks again.