# Firebase onDataChange not firing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve some data from Firebase. Here is my event listener that never gets fired, neither onCancelled method. I have tried the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851052/android-firebase-ondatachange-is-not-called). I've checked the rules. I have reading permissions. I added some wait time

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


     Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSign);

     TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

     Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

     FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     databaseReference = database.getReference();

     txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             createNewDbListener();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent1);
         }
     });

     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intentLoginP = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginPageActivity.class);
             startActivity(intentLoginP);
         }
     });

     btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intentSignUp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUpActivity.class);
             startActivity(intentSignUp);
         }
     });
 } 

private void createNewDbListener() {
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(databaseReference.child("counties")));

    databaseReference.child("counties").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("onDataChange", String.valueOf(databaseReference.child("counties")));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
             Log.e("DEBUG","OnCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });    } }
```

I've have done my research and I've tried almost everything. I do not know what the problem is. My function createNewDbListener() is entered and the first log gets fired.

**EDIT:** The log from my createNewDbListener function:

> 05-16 12:25:18.159 7153-7153/com.bla.dipproject D/DEBUG:
>   https://dipproject-3953a.firebaseio.com/counties

Comment: Can you post the log?

Comment: Print your log in 

@Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       }

Comment: You say that when you click on `txt` button, your MainActivity isn't opened?

Comment: @ashish: The thing is that it never reaches the OnDataChange method so nothing gets logged.

Comment: @AlexMamo: My Activity gets opened. I have a problem with my createNewDbListener. It enters the function, but the listener is not called at all.

Comment: Problem is the permissions. See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433940/1308990

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getAllUsersFromFirebase() {
    DatabaseReference UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constant.FIREBASE_USERS);

    UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            List<FcmUser> fcmUsers = new ArrayList<>();
            while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
                FcmUser fcmUser = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(FcmUser.class);

                 Log.e("Fcm User Name",fcmUser.name);
            }
            mOnGetAllUsersListener.onGetAllUsersSuccess(fcmUsers);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mOnGetAllUsersListener.onGetAllUsersFailure(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Try above sample code and comment on intent until not getting any response for debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.  Tried everything.  Turned out I had an incorrect configured access in the console.  Go to the firebase console and make sure your application is properly configured (settings -> project settings -> add app) and you have placed your google-services.json in the correct place.

Comment: I have read permissions and I have the google-services.json placed correctly.  I have downloaded it again just to be sure, but nothing happens.

Comment: Also the link to my database gets printed containing the first node. It just never enters the onDataChange method.

Comment: What kind of incorrect configuration did you have ?

Comment: Sorry not much more I can say - i use ChildEventListener & onChildAdded.  When using Firebase, I first had no success due to the upgrade of library names from GCM to firebase, then due to rules, then had no success because my authentication service had an incorrect API key, then refactored the package name and needed to get a new google-services.json for the new package name.

Some have mentioned there are two very similar ValueEventListener libraries - you may be using the wrong one - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458524/android-firebase-can%C2%B4t-add-valueeventlistener